# Panel in Windows Forms Application not clearing

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, custom-controls

I'm working on my project: [Beer Pong Management System][1], a Windows Forms application. I am currently trying to add a whole tournament mode to it. In a nutshell, I've created a TabControl, with the first tab page with the settings and setup and the second page the brackets.

There is a feature for each of the match-ups, that once there is a winner is decided, a yellow cancel button will appear in order to revert the tournament. However my issue is when i click the button the next match-up does not get removed in the series is going. See below:

[Image Here(not high enough rep to insert image)](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=18154)

I have tried to set the MatchUp to null,  I've tried dispose(), close(). even Parent.Controls.Remove().
Even after I switch tabs which is supposed to clear all, they still sit there when i come back.

I have a feeling I might be loosing a reference or something because I can't even push new teams into them, they just sit there with their buttons. 
 **Does anyone have any tips or know of any known issues that might be causing this? Thanks.**

[1]  _http://www.cs.rit.edu/~rmb1201/pages/code.shtml

Comment: *Very* unclear.  I can't even tell if the screen shot is one control or multiple controls.  Don't see a panel, don't see a tab control.  Don't see any code.

Comment: sorry let me reiterate.

When I create the tourney. I create an array of MatchUps for each bracket depth (Starting, Quarters, Semis, Finals). Each of these match ups have a button to pick which team wins. Once chosen the other team will be disabled and the button you clicked will turn to a yellow back button. Once two consecutive teams have done this I set the next bracket depth's matchup from the winners of the previous two. Whats supposed to happen, is if i hit the back button, the next bracket depth is supposed to dispose of the match up and revert the previous 2 to the start state.

Comment: I think for what you're asking, you're going to have to post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this snippet can help you identify the problem:

```
    public string GetControlSummary(Control rootControl, int level)
    {
        string result = "";
        foreach (Control childControl in rootControl.Controls)
        {
            result += new string(' ', level * 4) + childControl.Name + " (" + childControl.GetType().Name + ")\r\n";
            result += GetControlSummary(childControl, level + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Just pass the tabPage or Panel you added your controls to; it will give you a list of all controls and sub-controls you have added. If the controls are not in the list, they also shouldn't be painted.

Comment: What a great tool (in general as well). Thanks for it. From it looks like by the report it sends, I am creating duplicate controls, which means i have a rogue 'new' somewhere in my code. Thanks.